# ModulesNotFound Error when running python3 in shell script

Tags: python, bash

I have my python3 path under `/usr/bin`, any my pip path under `/.local/bin` of my local repository.
With some pip modules installed, I can run my code successfully through `python3 mycode.py`.

But I tried to run the shell script:

```
#!/usr/bin
echo "starting now..."
nohup python3 mycode.py > log.txt 2>&1 &
echo $! > pid
echo "mycode.py started at pid: "
cat pid
```

and my python code:

mycode.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from aiocqhttp import CQHttp, Event, Message, MessageSegment
...
...
...
```

It gives me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mycode.py", line 2, in <module>
    from aiocqhttp import CQHttp, Event, Message, MessageSegment
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aiocqhttp'
```

I tried to replace the interpreter of the shell script with my local path, but it doesn't help. How should I run my python codes using the shell script?

Comment: How are you executing the shell script?

Comment: Can you please provide the output of `echo $PYTHONPATH` in both your shell script and your local env? This is likely due to either an issue with env vars or execution location

Comment: I use `sudo bash run.sh`

Comment: `echo $PYTHONPATH` gives me nothing. Just a blank line

Comment: Will `sudo python3 mycode.py` break?

Comment: yeah sudo python3 mycode.py gives the same error

Comment: I tried `chmod 777 run.sh` but i cant run the script without sudo

Comment: OK, it's very likely that `aiocqhttp` is installed in your home directory so that `python3` cannot find the library when invoked from `sudo` (as root). Try `python3 -c 'import aiocqhttp; print(aiocqhttp.__file__)'` to confirm my guess.

Comment: `/home/a495488027/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiocqhttp/__init__.py`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, the `aiocqhttp` was installed in your home directory, and when you invoke the script by `sudo`, `python3` will not be able to know to search in your home (because it is root that is running the process). You may solve it using these two approaches:

Method 1:

```
sudo -H pip3 install -U aiocqhttp
```

Install this module system-wide so that every user can find it.

Method 2:

```
sudo PYTHONPATH=/home/a495488027/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages python3 mycode.py
```

Temporarily add the python module search path to `sudo` and run the code. This is when you doesn't want to install the package system-wide.

---

Back to your problem,

```
sudo PYTHONPATH=/home/a495488027/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages bash script.sh
```

should do the work.

Comment: This works, thank you. But I can't use method1 since my pip is installed under my local repository. Method 2 and 3 works fine but my purpose of using shell script is that I don't want to use a long command to run the python script. I'm using the google cloud and it;s unlikely other VPS which the default user is not root. I added the PYTHONPATH to .bashrc and use `sudo PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH bash script.sh` to run my script. Is there any way that I can add the PYTHONPATH globally so that I can straightly use `sudo bash script.sh` to start my script?

Comment: I edited the sudoer file and added `Default env_keep += "PYTHONPATH"` and now I can execute my script with sudo.

Comment: Um, instead of `pip` you may also try `python3 -m pip install XXX`. And as for the path, another possibility is to set `PYTHONPATH` inside the script.

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution: install the same that you have installed with sudo and then it will be accesible for all users